# docker vs docker-compose nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "httpstat.us" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:21

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a very peculiar issue with [this set](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5b225aa69ce11af7b931dbf38acc0340) of docker files:

docker run will do what I want whereas docker-compose will not

I'm quite noob'ed with Docker hence this probably rather simple question - and I apologise in advance!

- but I just cannot pinpoint my err

`docker run -p 80:8080 -i -t lakrids_devlakrids
172.17.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2017:23:29:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6979 "-" "curl/7.29.0"`

but if I start the same container with docker-compose I get

`docker-compose up devlakrids
Recreating devlakrids
Attaching to devlakrids
devlakrids      | 2017/02/01 23:28:19 [emerg] 11#11: host not found in upstream "httpstat.us" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:21
devlakrids      | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "httpstat.us" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:21
devlakrids exited with code 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what *made my day* (am forever grateful to Mr C. Eastwood) :)

The nginx container doubles as a reverse proxy in my design - and handles the 443 security end of things - allowing 'ordinary' application servers to deal with the business logic:

```
# ./docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  proxy:
    build: ./shared/proxy
    networks:
    - sand
    links:
    - devlakrids:devlakrids
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443

  # sand[kassen]
  #
  devlakrids:
    build: ./sand/current/spark
    expose:
    - "4567"
    tmpfs: /tmp
    volumes:
    - ./sand/current/:/mnt/lakrids
    - ./shared/sand/:/shared
    links:
    - sandmysql
    networks:
    - sand
    - sanddb
```

```
# ./shared/proxy/services.conf

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name dev.lakrids.xxxx.xxx;

        # Path for SSL config/key/certificate
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/xxx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/xxxx.pem;
        include /etc/nginx/includes/ssl.conf;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
                proxy_pass http://devlakrids:4567;
        }

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

```
# ./shared/proxy/includes/proxy.conf
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

With this – all that was left to do was `docker-compose up` by and large ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two possible culprits:

- `nginx` is a funny beast: if the upstream goes down while `nginx` is already running, then `nginx` keeps running. However, if upstream is not reachable on `nginx` start, the latter will fail to start. To solve this you might need to add a startup script to you `nginx` container testing for upstreams to be up before starting `nginx`;
- try to add `links` explicitly: somehow we had this issue that the `nginx` docker did not see other machines implicitly defined via `compose` service names.

Finally, one really forgotten option is: you do not specify anywhere in the files that you show where the `httpstat.us` service is started within the docker engine, so it is actually surprising that it works for you without compose.

Answer (score 1):

From the description, the image you are running outside of compose is likely to be different from the image you run inside compose, or you have different volume mounts. To resolve your error, I'd update your nginx.conf with an upstream definition:

```
daemon off;
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
   upstream httpstat.us {
       least_conn;
       server httpstat.us:80 fail_timeout=60s max_fails=2;
   }

   sendfile on;
   server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name dev.lakrids.premier-is.dk;

      location / {
         proxy_pass http://httpstat.us/;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      }
   }
}
```